# How to clear content of a lot of text files fast under Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, logging, text-editing, file-unlocking

I have a folder with logs.

This folder contains a lot of log files. I cannot delete these files because server keeps it. But I can remove content of every file. It is very annoying to open each file and remove content.

Can you provide ideas to make it faster?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: You want something like `for f in *.log; do :>"$f"; done` or the Windows equivalent.

Comment: I use Wnidows OS

Comment: What's `Wnidows OS`?

Comment: I use Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Save the below code as a batch file and Run it.

You can save the trouble of typing the command everytime `:)`.

Change `M:\Newfolder\` & `*.txt` to reflect your path & log file extension respectively.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R M:\Newfolder\ %%G IN (*.txt) DO (
    TYPE nul > %%G
)
pause
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can try to create a Macro to automate what you want to do.

Check out the first answer provided by ellak [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837629/clear-contents-of-multiple-files-in-notepad)

Open all your Log Files at once and then Run this Macro Everytime.

If you want to automate even that (opening all your Log Files at once) then Run the Batch Script below.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R M:\Newfolder\ %%G IN (*.txt) DO (
    notepad++.exe %%G
)
pause
```

So the next time you want to clear your Log Files, Simply

1. Run the Batch Script provided
2. Run the Macro from Notepad++

There is a way to run them both from the same script but this requires NPPExec Plugins that I'm not too familiar with. Please let me know if you want it with the plugin or if the solution provided above will suffice.

Comment: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: That means the file is being used. You can't clear the contents of a file that you have opened (in notepad or some other application)

Comment: At this moment I can open this file using notepade++ and clear content and save file

Comment: I thought the purpose of asking the question was to avoid doing it manually. Please try to find out the Application using these Logs. End it and run the script again.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid make it manually. Application server keep these logs files. And I don't want to stop it. hotepade ++ allow this

Comment: How about a script to open the file in notepad++ & clear. In other words it should be possible to automate what your'e doing manually to achieve the same task

Comment: can you provide this script?

Comment: Updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought if the file is being used and you can't clear it, and Notepad++ is allowing you to clear it why not just use a script in Notepad++ like @Dhiwakar Ravikumar mentioned?

If scripts are out of the question, and assuming you have quite a bit of log files, why not just open them all in Notepad++, select the first open tab and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>? That would select all the text in the file, delete it, save the file, then close it and then just do the same thing (like a script)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation as yours, where a log file is continuously written by some app and I have to clear the content without closing the app. Fortunately I have only 1 file and I can open it in Notepad++, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. In case there are multiple files just use the following PowerShell script

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse log*.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $fs = [IO.FileStream]::new($_.FullName, `
        [IO.FileMode]::Truncate, [IO.FileAccess]::Write, [IO.FileShare]::Write)
    $fs.Close()
}
```

<sub>(Alternatively call `$fs.SetLength(0)` to truncate the file if `[IO.FileMode]` is not `Truncate`)</sub>

This works because **the log file was opened in [`FILE_SHARE_WRITE` mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)**, contrary to many people's beliefs that you can't delete or edit a file in Windows while it's opened. Subsequent opens must also be in shared mode. That's why `>` or `>>` in cmd or PowerShell doesn't work, because they open the file normally. Here's a very simple C++ to demonstrate how to create a file in shared mode

```c++
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
#include <windows.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    srand(unsigned(time(nullptr)));
    const wchar_t* fileName = LR"(D:\logs\log1.txt)";

    // Create file with shared read/write permission
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(fileName,
        GENERIC_WRITE,                      // open for writing
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, // share for reading/writing
        NULL,                               // default security
        CREATE_NEW,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,              // normal file
        NULL);                              // no attr. template

    if (h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            DWORD n;
            char str[64];
            int l = sprintf_s(str, sizeof str, "%d: %d\n", i, rand());
            WriteFile(h, str, l, &n, NULL); FlushFileBuffers(h);
            Sleep(3000);
        }
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
}
```

It creates `log1.txt` and writes to it periodically. I also have the below PowerShell script to create another shared log file

```powershell
$fs = [IO.FileStream]::new('D:\logs\log2.txt', `
    [IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate, [IO.FileAccess]::Write, [IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 100; $i++) {
    $t = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$i $(Get-Random)`r`n")
    $fs.Write($t, 0, $t.Length); $fs.Flush()
    Sleep 3
}
$fs.Close()
```

After that I ran the command on top and all the log files are cleared

Answer (score -1):

From a command line:

```
FOR /R C:\YourFolder %f IN (*.LOG) DO TYPE NUL>%f
```

Or, from a batch file:

```
FOR /R C:\YourFolder %%f IN (*.LOG) DO TYPE NUL>%%f
```

Comment: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: How you clearing it manually?

Comment: I open this file using notepade++ and clear content and save file

Comment: If another process has the file locked, I'm not sure how you can be clearing and saving it.

Comment: I have tried a lot of methods on this and they all involve doing quite a lot of work (installing software or programming). Your simplest answer is to boot into safe mode (command-line only) and the above solutions should work. This will be fine for a one-off, though not something to do regularly. I tried NP++ on a file held open for writing and got an error, effectively the same as you saw, so I don't know how it works for you. Which logs are you talking about?

Comment: What do you want to ask? I provided all information! it is usual logs files contains text

Comment: @AFH you'll only get the error if you disable sharing while opening the file. One project in one of my previous companies write log exactly that way and I also have to open notepad++ to truncate the content while the file is being opened, because the lock only disable file deletion but not modification. Just change [`dwShareMode` in `CreateFileW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) and you'll see

Comment: @AFH [see the simple way to do it](https://superuser.com/a/1714668/241386). No need for any programming tool